# Computing $\left(\frac{\partial x^{i}}{\partial y^{j}}\right)_{p}$ for $\mathbb{R}$ valued component functions.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Consider the manifold $(\mathbb{R}^{2}, \mathcal{O})$ (where $\mathcal{O}$ is the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$) be equipped with the atlas $\mathcal{A} = \{(\mathbb{R}^{2}, x), (\mathbb{R}^{2}, y)\}$
such that $x: \mathbb{R}^{2} \to \mathbb{R}^{2}$, where $x(a,b) := (a,b)$, and  $y: \mathbb{R}^{2} \to \mathbb{R}^{2}$ where $y(a,b) : =(a,b + a^{3})$.

We are asked to compute the $(\text{dim}\mathbb{R}^{2})^{2} = 4$ objects $\left(\frac{\partial x^{i}}{\partial y^{j}}\right)_{p} := \partial_{j}(x^{i} \ \circ \ y^{-1})(y(p))$.

---

I found the inverse of $y$ to be defined as $y^{-1}(u,v) = (u, v-u^{3})$ and so we have $x^{i} \ \circ \ y^{-1} : \mathbb{R^{2}} \to \mathbb{R}$ where using the chart map $x$ we have $(x \ \circ \ y^{-1})(u,v) = (u, v-u^{3})$. In the solution for $\left(\frac{\partial x^{2}}{\partial y^{1}}\right)_{p}$, for example, the author says to differentiate $x^{2}$ (the second component function of $x$) with respect to the first entry (which in this case would be the symbol $u$) which he claims would give us

$$\partial_{1}(x^{2} \ \circ \ y^{-1})(a, b+a^{3}) = -3u^{2} = -3a^{2}. (*)$$

However, in the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mACNdkRdHEA&list=PLFeEvEPtX_0RQ1ys-7VIsKlBWz7RX-FaL&index=5), there's a lot of steps skipped and I can't seem to understand how he arrived at this solution. Do we have to perform the multidimensional chain rule for each $\left(\frac{\partial x^{i}}{\partial y^{j}}\right)_{p}$? I.e., maybe for the example above, if $$h(a, b+a^{3}) := x^{2}(y^{-1}(a, b+a^{3})) $$ then (writing something like the following, where $u=a$, $v = b+a^{3}$)
$$Dh(u,v) = Dx^{2}(y^{-1}(u,v)))Dy^{-1}(u,v)?$$

If someone could please walk me through these steps or show me that I'm completely overthinking it would be greatly appreciated.

---

$(*)$ Another thought: It seems like, since $x$ is the identity function on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, we don't need to use the chain rule explicitly and can just take the partial derivative of $x^{i}$ with respect to either $u$ or $v$.

Comment: The video is 1h30min ... can you tell us which part of the video is relevant ?

Comment: Using slimmer notation should resolve the issue: As you say, the author differentiates the second component of $(u,v-u^3)$ with respect to the first entry $u\,.$ This derivative is $-3u^2\,.$

Comment: @Digitallis - Of course, the part where he presents my concern is at minute 40:00.

Comment: @KurtG - That makes sense, but why can we just assume that $\partial_{1}(x^{2} \ \circ \ y^{-1})(a, b+a^{3}) = -3u^{2} = -3a^{2}. (*)$ means to just differentiate $x^{2}$ with respect to the first entry without having to use the chain rule since we have a derivative of a composition of functions? Thank you.

Comment: As Digitalis pointed out in the answer: no need for the chain rule. The composite function does us the favour of being a simple expression that we can differentiate. This is one of those many cases where DG notation is more intimidating than it has to be. Having said that: there are situations where the chain rule literally [shines](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4729311/949989).

Comment: @KurtG. - Thank you, Kurt, your comments and Digitallis' answer cleared up my questions. Also, I like the quote you provided in the answer you linked :-).

Comment: Those points go to Sidney Coleman who was talking about the career of a physicist and the simple harmonic oscillator. When they are going to torture you with pull backs and push forwards: just remember the good old chain rule. :)

Comment: @KurtG - Hi Kurt, I had a quick question about some of the elementary parts of this I can't seem to convince myself of: Notice that the chart transition map here is written as $(x^{i} \circ y^{-1})(y(p))$. Since $y^{-1}(y(p)) = p$, why isn't the chart transition function simply $x^{i}$? For example, why is $(x^{2} \circ y^{-1})(y(p)) = x^{2}(p) = b$ incorrect?

Comment: This looks correct. Who said that it is not?

Comment: @KurtG. - That's what I thought too. But according to what's written below, $(x^{2} \circ y^{-1})(y(p)) = b + a^{3} $? Maybe I'm misunderstanding something here.

Comment: Where below? To summarize what I know: $x(a,b)=(a,b),\;y(a,b)=(a,b+a^3),\;y^{-1}(u,v)=(u,v-u^3)\,.$ Hence: $(x\circ y^{-1})(u,v)=(u,v-u^3)$ and $(x\circ y^{-1})(y(a,b))=(a,b)\,.$ If "below" means you want to discuss anything with Digitalis please go ahead and to so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for the chain rule. As you showed$$ x \circ y^{-1} : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2 : (u,v) \mapsto(u,v-u^3).$$

Therefore define a function $$ g : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R : (u,v) \mapsto v-u^3 $$
notice that this function is exactly $g = x^2\circ y^{-1}.$

Can you compute the partial derivative of the above function with respect to the first component $u$? Yes !
$$ \frac{\partial g}{\partial u} = \frac{\partial }{\partial u}(v-u^3) = -3u^2 = \partial_1(x^2\circ y^{-1})(u,v)$$
Now fix a specific point $p = (a,b)$ and evaluate the above partial derivatives at $y(p) = (a,b+a^3)$ and you find that

$$\partial_1(x^2\circ y^{-1})(a,b+a^3) = -3a^2$$

Comment: I think this is starting to make more sense, my only concern still is why don't we need the chain rule? How is this situation different from when we need to apply the chain rule to a composition of functions?

Comment: I guess you could use the chain rule if you wanted to. However why would you want to make your life more difficult. The chain rule is a tool to take the derivative of a composition of functions. This does not mean that you *have* to use it whenever you take the derivative of a composition of functions.

Comment: @TaylorRendon But if you are going to start working on more abstract manifolds $M$ you can't use the chain rule since the map $x$ will be $M \to \mathbb R^2$  will not be differentiable (at least in the usual sense.)

Answer (score 0):

This is much simpler than it sounds and as the comment above implies, it's due to poor notation.  You've got two charts, each with a function from $\mathbb{R^2}$ to $\mathbb{R^2}$ and denoted by $x$ and $y$. Since these are vector-valued functions of two variables, this can be improved by bolding them $\mathbb{x}$ and $\mathbb{y}$.  Then the notation for the 4 partial derivatives using $x$ and $y$ does not seem right to me since $x$ and $y$ are not being used as dependent and independent variables as the usual partials notation assumes. In other words, just express the transition function $x \circ y^{-1}$ as a function of $u$ and $v$ as you did and the 4 objects you want form the standard Jacobian, namely $1, 0, -3u^2$ and $1$ with some care to get each into the right spot in the resulting 2 x 2 matrix. Using $a$ and $b$ would just mean putting in an actual point. Added: above excellent answer appeared while I was writing this.