# Why can derivatives be used as a basis for one-forms/covectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

I'm studying for general relativity and as such I'm learning tensor algebra. I'm following Schutz's book where denotes covectors with a tilde such as $\tilde{w}$ and vectors with the familiar arrow $\vec{e}$.

He defines the gradient of $\phi$ as the one-form $\tilde{d}\phi$ such that is has elements $\tilde{d}\phi = (\partial_i\phi) = \left( \dfrac{\partial\phi}{\partial x^{0}}, \dfrac{\partial\phi}{\partial x^{1}}, \dfrac{\partial\phi}{\partial x^{2}}, \dfrac{\partial\phi}{\partial x^{3}} \right)$. They of course transform as covectors such that
$$(\tilde{d}\phi)_{\bar{a}} = {\Lambda^{b}}_\bar{a} (\tilde{d}\phi)_b$$
then it can be deduced that ${\Lambda^{b}}_\bar{a} = \dfrac{\partial x^b}{\partial x^\bar{a}}$.

He then claims that you can use these gradients to form a basis for one-forms such that $\tilde{d}x^a = w^a$. I don't understand this derivation because he uses the following relationships:
$$\dfrac{\partial x^b}{\partial x^a} = {\delta^a}_b \ \ \ \text{and}\ \ \ \tilde{w}^a(\vec{e}_b) = {\delta^a}_b$$

Why is the first relationship true? I understand that for Cartesian coordinates this is true but what about in the general case? Couldn't I always define a new coordinate system $(x', y')$ where $x' = x'(y')$ and $y' = y'(x')$? Clearly then their various partial derivatives do not necessarily vanish. Does this mean the claim that $\tilde{d}x^a$ forming a covector basis only holds for Cartesian coordinates?

Comment: If we call the standard Euclidean coordinates $r^i$, and $\phi = (x^1,\dots, x^n)$ then you can check that $\partial/\partial x^i$ is the pushforward under $\phi^{-1}$ of $\partial/\partial r^i$.

Comment: Coordinates are just labels by which we specify points on a manifold and they allow us to partially differentiate functions defined on the manifold. The function $(x^0,\dots x^3)\mapsto x^b$ clearly has the partial derivative given by that "first" relationship, regardless what coordinates we have used. Why partial derivatives form a basis of the tangent space is handled in any differential geometry book (or briefly [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4729311/949989) for example).

Comment: Differentials $dx^i$ are a basis of the cotangent space. Imho the strength of this modern view point is that a lot of stuff (coordinate transformations, pull backs, pushforwards) can be deduced simply from the chain rule. And can be memorized quite well in that way.