# nabla in spherical coordinates using tensor transformation rule

Tags: tensors, coordinate-systems

Usually people derive nabla coordinates in spherical system using orthogonal basis or another tricks, I just want to apply general rule for $\left(\begin{array}[c] 00 \\ 1\end{array}\right)$ tensor.
As I understand, if
\begin{equation}
d f = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z}dz
\end{equation}
Then in cartesian coordinates
\begin{equation}
\nabla_i = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}
\end{equation}
for $\left(\begin{array} 00 \\ 1\end{array}\right)$ tensor coordinates after changing atlas from $X\rightarrow Y$:
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}[c] xx = r\sin(\theta)\cos(\varphi)\\ y =r\sin(\theta)\sin(\varphi)\\ z=r\cos(\theta) \end{array}\Rightarrow \begin{array}[c] rr = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\\ \theta = arctan(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}/z)\\ \varphi = arctan(y/x) \end{array}
\end{equation}
have to transform like:
\begin{equation}
\nabla_k =\nabla_i\dfrac{\partial x^i}{\partial y^k}
\end{equation}
So
\begin{equation}
\nabla_r = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\dfrac{\partial x^i}{\partial r}=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial r}+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial r}+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z}\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial r}=
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\sin(\theta)\cos(\varphi)+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\sin(\theta)\sin(\varphi)+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z}\cos(\theta)
\end{equation}
but wikipedia says:
\begin{equation}
\nabla_r = \dfrac{\partial }{\partial r}
\end{equation}

Comment: I don't see a contradiction between your formula and what Wikipedia says.

Comment: but I am not getting $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial r}$ from tensor transformation rule

Comment: The notation $\nabla_r$ is gratuitous because it *is* $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\,.$ I do not know what exactly you mean by tensor transformation rule. I have verified many times that all we need is just the [chain rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4729236/deriving-the-gradient-operator-in-spherical-coordinates/4729311#4729311) and that is what you actually did also.

Comment: by transformation law I mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor#:~:text=.-,The%20transformation%20law,-for%20an%20order

Comment: The chain rule states that $\partial/\partial{r}=\partial{x}/\partial{r}\partial/\partial{x}+\partial{y}/\partial{r}\partial/\partial{y}+\partial{z}/\partial{r}\partial/\partial{z}$.

Comment: ok but for $\nabla_{\theta}=\dfrac{1}{r}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \theta}$ where does $\dfrac{1}{r}$ come from?

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4539422/in-multivariable-calculus-why-do-we-normalize-frac-partial-partial-theta/4540699#4540699).